# Display next line on refresh/load

Tags: php

I have a text file and I am able to display each line randomly everytime my page loads with php.  I was wondering if its possible with PHP code to echo a new line every time a page is loaded in the same order as in the text file?

this is what i have so far to display a random line. Now im trying to figure out how to cycle through the text file line per line on every load of the page

```
<?php
$f_contents = file("file.txt");
$line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
echo $line."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: show us your code please :)

Comment: You could use SESSION to know which line to load.

Comment: be more efficient to put the file lines in a a db

Comment: Can you clear your question. I mean what are you getting now and what exactly you want. If possible please share us the code also.

Comment: every time the page is loaded i want to display the next line in the text file

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to get the current position in the file (using [`ftell()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php)) after reading each line, save that position in the user's [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), and restore it (using [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)) before reading the next line. Compared to using `file()`, this has the advantage of only requiring that one line be read into memory at a time, instead of the entire file (although changes made to the file can result in partial lines being read, which can be worked around if necessary).

```
<?php

// Load session and open tips file
session_start();
$fp = fopen('README', 'r');

// Go to where we left off
if (isset($_SESSION['offset'])) {
    fseek($fp, $_SESSION['offset']);
}

// Read that line
$line = fgets($fp);
if ($line === false) {
    // Hit end of file; go back to the beginning
    fseek($fp, 0);
    $line = fgets($fp);
}

// Save the position of the next line and close the file
$_SESSION['offset'] = ftell($fp);
fclose($fp);

// Output the line
echo '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($line) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$line_number = isset($_SESSION['LINE_NO']) ? $_SESSION['LINE_NO'] + 1 : 1;
$_SESSION['LINE_NO'] = $line_number;
$f_contents = file("file.txt");
$line = $f_contents[$line_number];
echo $line."<br>";
?>
```

if anything is not clear i'll be glad to help

Comment: Wouldn't you need a `session_start()` in the beginning ?

Comment: Im trying ur code and it keeps displaying my second line in my text file on each load

Comment: That is correct sir, answers will never be full solution, they are to help with the idea

Comment: @AndrewGarcia check if your sessions are enabled

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, depending on how you want to present the data:

To send a line to users who do not need to log on, you can either keep the pointer in SESSION (though it will reset to zero if they close their browser) or set a cookie to act as a pointer, which will retain the data until it expires or is deleted.

For users who log on (say a tip of the day) you can keep a record of where they are in the file in a database field and retrieve this whenever a line is needed.  You could also save the data in xml if you don't want to use a db.
This has the advantage of working from any computer but is computationally a little more complex.

If your file has many lines, a database table or xml file would be more efficient than iterating through a text file.